# JavaScript Class Function not accessible by Event Listener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, array.prototype.map

The toggleLid function defined in my class is not working when called in an event listener. The individual 'backpack' objects are defined elsewhere. The browser is not throwing any errors in the console. Any advice is appreciated!

```
function Backpack (
    name,
    lidOpen
    
) {
    this.name = name;
    this.lidOpen = lidOpen;

    this.toggleLid = (lidStatus) => {
        this.lidOpen = lidStatus;
    };
};

const backPackList = [bag1, bag2];

const content = backPackList.map((backpack) => {
    let backpackArticle = document.createElement("article");
    backpackArticle.classList.add("backpack");
    backpackArticle.setAttribute("id", backpack.id)
    backpackArticle.innerHTML = `
    <h1>${backpack.name}<h1>
    <h2>${backpack.lidOpen}<h1>
    <button class='lid-toggle'>Toggle Lid</button>
    `;

    const button = backpackArticle.querySelector(".lid-toggle")

    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        backpack.toggleLid(!backpack.lidOpen)
    })

    return backpackArticle;
});
```

Comment: What makes you think that `toggleLid` is not working? Did you expect the HTML to update on click? Why?

Comment: You're right, I jumped the gun. The function did update the object but did not update the HTML on the fly - I learned JavaScript using React, is this not possible in Vanilla JS?

Comment: Vanilla JS doesn't have any data binding functionality. You will have to develop this yourself. This data binding functionality is the one main thing that frameworks/libraries give you for which the DOM API and JS have no out-of-the-box solution. *is this not possible in Vanilla JS* If that were not possible, not framework would be able to do it either.

Comment: I recommend this for a start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1RCCJtQoUs Two-way data-binding is trivially easy to achieve in Vanilla JS. I recommend you turn away from any frameworks until you have mastered the language itself and the native DOM API.

Comment: The entire point of React's existence and why is was named "React" is re-rendering the changed parts of your app whenever its state changes. If you want the same with Vanilla JS, you have to manually re-render after changing the state.